# Chart js (plugin annotation) label overflow issue

Tags: charts, chartjs-plugin-annotation

Need to know possible solutions to resolve such issue:
[image]

My annotation object looks like this:

```
{
      type: 'label',
      borderRadius: 0,
      borderWidth: 0,
      content: content,
      font: {
        size: 8,
        weight: 'bold'
      },
      position: {
        x: 'center',
        y: 'end'
      },
      xValue: name,
      yValue: value
    }
```

Is any way maybe to add a free space above bar to show annotation properly?

P.S. I can't set max value for Y because it's dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could set the `clip` option to false in order to draw the label outside of chart area.

Here you can find the doc: https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/guide/configuration.html#top-level-options

Here an example:

```
const options = {
  plugins: {
    annotation: {
      clip: false,
      annotations: {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: If you don't have enough space on the top of the chart, use layout.padding.top options of chart configuration to have space on top of chart area

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding to the graph.
options: {
layout: {
padding: 40
}
}
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/padding.html

Comment: options: {
        layout: {
            padding: {
                left: 50
            }
        }
    } You can add padding top,bottom, left,right also